# Bootstrap Vue Carousel height does not fit to full screen

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, carousel, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap Vue to create my carousel. The carousel contains 3 images that allow users to cycle through. I am able to display the images that fit the height and width of my laptop screen size. However, as I slowly reduce the screen size to mobile, the height does not feet the screen anymore. Below are my codes and screenshots

Update: I still cannot solve this issue, can anyone here me?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-carousel
      id="carousel-1"
      v-model="slide"
      :interval="4000"
      controls
      indicators
      background="#ababab"
      style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
      @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
      @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
    >
      <!-- Text slides with image -->
      <b-carousel-slide
        caption="First slide"
        text="Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum."
        img-src="https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080"
      ></b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slides with custom text -->
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080">
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
      </b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slides with image only -->
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080"></b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>

    <p class="mt-4">
      Slide #: {{ slide }}
      <br>
      Sliding: {{ sliding }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      slide: 0,
      sliding: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSlideStart(slide) {
      this.sliding = true;
    },
    onSlideEnd(slide) {
      this.sliding = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Desktop screen:

[image: Desktop Screen]

Mobile screen:

[image: Mobile Screen]

Comment: did you tried `backround-size:cover;`? or you could try `@media` in your css

Comment: @UdhayTitus i've not tried yet. Maybe you can help?

Comment: you have to use `background-size:cover` it will be works for your all screen. Or create jsfiddle what you have tried

Comment: Hi @UdhayTitus. I've used background-size: cover and it works. However, Now i want to dynamically render the <b-carousel-slide> component using an array of objects and for loop. I've posted a new thread regarding this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980098/cannot-render-images-dynamically-to-carousel-vuejs                     Furthermore, here is my js fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/Issaki1/40yf526z/10/

Comment: in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Issaki1/40yf526z/10/) how you need the background image? or you can apply dynamic css

Comment: What do you mean "how you need the background image"?

Comment: do you want this background image in jquery

Comment: No, I do not want it in jquery

Comment: Is it possible to add working carousel in jsfiddle that will be easy to find the problem

Answer (score 6):

```
<b-carousel-slide v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index">
   <template v-slot:img>
      <img
       class="d-block class-name"
       width="1024"
       :src="slide"
       alt="image slot">
    </template>
</b-carousel-slide>


<style>
.class-name {
   height:100vh;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
<style>
    .carousel-item img {
        height:100vh!important ;
    }
</style>
```

I also encountered the same problem ,and I set the style of img to the above code then problem solved!!

I hope this helps you although it's been a long time since you asked.