# Cannot render images dynamically to carousel Vuejs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, carousel, bootstrap-vue

I've set up a carousel using bootstrap-vue. I used a for loop and an array of objects to dynamically create the  component. In each of the slide, I will include a text as well as a background image. I was able to render the texts dynamically. However, the background image only appeared at the first slide. For subsequent slides, the image will not be rendered anymore. What seems to be the problem? Below are my codes and a screenshot of the result

Update: I am still not able to get this to work. Can anyone help me?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-carousel
      id="carousel-1"
      v-model="slide"
      :interval="4000"
      controls
      indicators
      background="#ababab"
      style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
      @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
      @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
    >
      <!-- Text slides with image -->
      <b-carousel-slide
        v-for="item in carouselItems"
        :key="item.id"
        :text="item.text"
        :style="{ 'background-image' : 'url(\'' + item.image + '\')' }"
      ></b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>
    <ProductList/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// 1. Loading images asychronously later on from S3
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659676/how-to-load-image-src-url-in-vuejs-asyncronously
import ProductList from "@/components/product/ProductList.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    ProductList
  },
  data() {
    return {
      carouselItems: [
        {
          id: 1,
          image: "https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080",
          text: "Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum. (1)"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          image: "https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080",
          text: "Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum. (2)"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          image: "https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080",
          text: "Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum. (3)"
        }
      ],
      slide: 0,
      sliding: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSlideStart(slide) {
      this.sliding = true;
    },
    onSlideEnd(slide) {
      this.sliding = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

Carousel when it was first rendered
[image: Carousel when it was first rendered]

Subsequent slide not display image
[image: Subsequent slide not display image]

Returning back to slide 1 and the background image is gone
[image: Returning back to slide 1 and the background image is gone]

Comment: I think the issue is with how you have written your v-bind:style in b-carousel-slide. Try this: `:style="{ backgroundImage : url(item.image) }"`

Comment: Hi, it did not work. The carousel did not even appear with your code

Answer (score 2):

As you use bootstrap-vue library, you can use "caption" attribute instead of "text" and "img-src" instead of style:background. Because `b-carousel-slide` component override style tag.

```
<b-carousel-slide
        v-for="item in carouselItems"
        :key="item.id"
        :caption="item.text"
        :img-src="item.image"
      ></b-carousel-slide>
```

If you want to have a custom style for your crousal you can set an additional class attr to your tag like:

```
<b-carousel-slide
      class="MyCustomClass"
      ....
      ></b-carousel-slide>
<style>
    .MyCustomClass {
        width: 100%;    
        object-fit: cover; 
    }
</style>
```

But pay attention that the carousal you are using is either responsive and also full-width. I think your problem is something else.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I was able to dynamically render the images. However, the reason why I used style:background is to make the background image responsive to mobile. Now that is removed, the images are no longer responsive. What should i do?

Comment: ajafari to further explain, I want my image to fit to screen across all devices. How am i able to achieve that?

Comment: I suggest you to assign a class to **<b-carousel-slide class="myStyle">** and work on add or override custom style items to achieve your wanted style. Although ```b-carousel-style``` has **w-100** class internally.

Comment: Hi ajafari, but what I want is to achieve something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965592/bootstrap-vue-carousel-height-does-not-fit-to-full-screen

Comment: Oh! I got it you want to have height fit image. Didn't you try to use ```object-fit: cover;```?